# MariaDB, Is is possible call package method from other shema

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB 10.3 allow to create ORACLE packages

I used example described https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-package-body/

```
use SX;

SET sql_mode=ORACLE;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SX.PA_TEST AS
  FUNCTION test(eid INT);
END;
$$

CREATE PACKAGE BODY SX.PA_TEST AS
  PROCEDURE test(eid INT) AS
  BEGIN
    ...
  END;
BEGIN
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

now then I try to do

```
use SY;

BEGIN 
    SX.PA_TEST.test(999);
END;
```

it throw error

```
Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=104) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.test(999);
```

I have to specify a schema in my code, but it looks like this not implemented in MariaDB.

Is there any option how to call package method with specifying scheme?
Could you please recommend any solution?

Thank you

Comment: Check [Oracle Comp.: Sql-Error when referencing database/schema in "select package-function from dual"](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16479).

Comment: Does it need `CALL`?

Comment: No, it doesn't need CALL, see https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12107
And in your code you mistyped - there should be PROCEDURE in the PACKAGE